# Setting a MP3 file as ringtone

Tags: android, android-studio, media-player, ringtone

I am working on media players .And trying to set the MP3 file as the ringtone when ever we click the button .As I am new in android devlopment can some one tell me how to do it

Answer (score 0):

```
File k = new File(path, "mysong.mp3"); // path is a file playing

ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, k.getAbsolutePath());
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "My Song title"); //You will have to populate 
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, 215454);
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "Band Name"); //You will have to populate this
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION, 230);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, false);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, false);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);

//Insert it into the database
Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k.getAbsolutePath());
Uri newUri = main.getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);

RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
  myActivity,
  RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE,
  newUri
);
```

Try above code, it will take first mp3 file then insert it into db using content provider, and then it will set type as rington.

Hope this helps

Thanks.